# Fork the actual mainnet from a specific block

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I would like to test some imbrications between many smartcontract on Ethereum, but :

- many of them are not available on testnets/are on different testnets.
- there is a significant history/status change for some of them and it would be difficult to correctly reproduce the current state.

So, in order to get as close as possible to the actual mainnet, is there a way to copy the current state of the entire blockchain, with all the transactions, and fork it at a specific block to test some features ?

The [official documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network) explains how to create a private network, but how can we create a private network based on a specific mainnet's block ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) with the `--fork` option.

> *Fork from another currently running Ethereum client at a given block. Input should be the HTTP location and port of the other client, e.g. `http://localhost:8545`. You can optionally specify the block to fork from using an @ sign: `http://localhost:8545@1599200`.*

So the actual command could look like this:

```
ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<your_infura_id>
```