# send ERC-20 tokens with solidity to user

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, remix

as you know, ERC-20 network has many tokens like `USDT`, `SHIB`, `LINK`, . . .

I want to create a website , when user need to buy `USDT` token I should send the `USDT` token in his wallet `or` use need to send `USDT` to another wallet on the blockchain and I want do all of these things into the blockchain, and the user could see the detail of his `USDT` transaction :

[USDT Transactions](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7)

now I have a big question about transfer tokens in ERC-20 network.

i write this codes in remix and solidity :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';

contract DEX {

    struct Token {
        string token;
        address contractAddress;
    }

    mapping(string => Token) public tokens;
    string[] public tokenLis;

    address public admin;

    constructor() {
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    function addToken(string memory token, address contractAddress) external {
        tokens[token] = Token(ticker,contractAddress);
        tokenLis.push(ticker);
    }

    function getTokenAddress(string memory token) external view returns(address moemory) {
       return tokens[token].contractAddress;
    }

    function sendToken(string memory token, address from , uint256 amount)
     external
      {

        IERC20(tokens[token].contractAddress).transferFrom(
            from,
            address(this),
            amount
        );


    }

}
```

I want to add dynamically tokens to my `website` and `smart contract`, for this write this codes :

```
  struct Token {
    string token;
    address contractAddress;
}

mapping(string => Token) public tokens;


function addToken(string memory token, address contractAddress) external {
    tokens[token] = Token(ticker,contractAddress);
    tokenLis.push(ticker);
}
```

I called `addToken` with this info :

`Token` : USDT

`contractAddress` : 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7 ( USDT mainnet contract address )

it's work and add success `USDT` in tokens .

now I want to send some `USDT` to the user with this function ( [imported the openzepelin IERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol)) :

```
function sendToken(string memory ticker , address from , uint256 amount)
 external
  {

    IERC20(tokens[ticker].contractAddress).transferFrom(
        from,
        address(this),
        amount
    );
}
```

now when I want to transfer amount from remix address one to remixaddress to into the `USDT` contract address it show me this error :

[image]
[image]

[image]

What is the problem? how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your contract is on a different network (Remix VM emulator) than the USDT contract (Ethereum mainnet), so they cannot interact. You can fork the mainnet and connect to the forked network from your Remix IDE, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850716/1693192) for more details.
2. Then you're probably going to run into another issue within the `sendToken()` function (since you don't cover it in your question, I'm assuming you haven't performed this step). In order to successfully invoke `transferFrom()`, the function caller (in this case your contract address) needs to be approved by the token owner (in this case the `from` variable) to spend their tokens. You can find more info in the ERC-20 [specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#approve) to the `approve()` function.

   Summary: The `from` address needs to invoke the `approve()` method on the token contract directly (not through your or any other contract), passing it your contract address as the first param, so that your contract is able to pull their tokens.

Comment: hi. thanks for answer my question . i have a lot of question about this . i ask them here . if you can answer me .

i should do this steps : 
`A:` in web3.js I should create wallet for user in this smartconract ( `USDT`);
`B:` in smart contract I should call the sendToken function
`C:` in that function I should check the approve of `sender` wallet address . 
`D:` if success every thing i should send token from `sender` wallet to `reciver` wallet.

**is it correct?**

Comment: @Kianoush Correct, assuming the `sender` has approved at least the sent amount validated in step C, and has sufficient balance to send in step D.

Comment: thank you my friend