# How can I use eth_estimateGas on a mint function when the public sale is closed?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, nft

```
function mint(uint256 addr, uint256 id) public payable {
    require(id < 10000000000, "id invalid");
    require(saleActive == true, "Public Sale not active!");
    require(msg.value >= mintPrice, "No enough Eth supplied!");
    require(availableSupply > 0, "Not enough supply of tokens"); 

    _safeMint(msg.sender, currentID.current());
    currentID.increment();
    availableSupply = availableSupply - 1;
  }
```

Let's say I have this mint function in an ERC721 contract. How can I use eth_estimateGas on this function when saleActive is false? In other words, how can I estimate the gas limit on a transfer event before the sale is active? When I run eth_estimateGas on this function, I get a transaction reverted error, with label "Public Sale Active!"

Answer (score 1):

You can fork the network where the contract is deployed, change the value on the forked network, and then estimate the gas after the value has been changed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850716/1693192) for example of creating a network fork with Ganache.

Comment: Would I have to deploy a contract on the network fork to do this?

Comment: @DanielZafman Only if it's not deployed on the source network already.