# when trying to withdraw BUSD from a smart contract am gettting Gas Estimate Error - JSON-RPC : 32000

Tags: deployment, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, openzeppelin

i would like to send BUSD to a smart contract and then only owner can withdraw these BUSD from this smart contract. can someone help me to program the same?

i tried below but doesn't think it will work.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../IERC20.sol";

contract TestBUSD {

    IERC20 tokenContract;
    address private owner;
    uint bal;

    constructor() payable {
        tokenContract = IERC20(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function Approvetokens(uint256 _tokenamount) public returns(bool){
       tokenContract.approve(address(this), _tokenamount);
       return true;
   }

    function GetUserTokenBalance() public view returns(uint256){ 
       return tokenContract.balanceOf(msg.sender);
   }

    function deposit(uint256 _tokenamount) payable public {
        tokenContract.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenamount);
        bal += msg.value;
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {    
        return owner;
    }
    
    function withdrawToken(address _tokenContract, uint256 _amount) payable external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw!");
        IERC20(_tokenContract);
        tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: On which network are you deploying the contract? The BSC mainnet, its local fork, non-forked emulator (e.g. the Remix VM), ... ?

Comment: right now on BSC testnet

Answer (score 0):

The `tokenContract` address [does not hold](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56) any smart contract on the BSC testnet (there is the [BUSD token](https://bscscan.com/address/0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56#code) on the same address on the mainnet).

Your `withdrawToken()` function sends an internal transaction to the `tokenContract` address, trying to execute its function `transfer()`, and expects to be returned a `bool` (as declared in the `IERC20` interface) from this internal transaction. However, since there's no contract on this address, no response is generated - the internal transaction fails, which makes the main transaction fail as well.

If you want to test your contract specifically on the BSC testnet, you need to use a token address that has an ERC20 token deployed. As far as I'm aware, there's currently no official BUSD release on the testnet, so you might have to use another token or your own dummy token instead.

Or if you want to just test the contract interacting with BSUD on a non-mainnet network, I'd recommend you to [fork the mainnet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850716/1693192) in your local emulator.